# Get ID of first cell in a specific table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Given,

```
<table id=ThisTable>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="ThisCell">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="NotThis">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="NorThis">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table
```

How can I use JQuery/Javascript to assign the ID of the first table cell in #ThisTable to the variable "Selected"?

The result in this case should look like:

```
var Selected = "ThisCell";
```

I need to get the first cell's ID without having any knowledge of what the ID is, probably using the :first selector. In addition, this isn't the only table on the page, so it must be referenced with its ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var Selected = $('#ThisTable td:first').attr('id');
```

This selects the first `td` element that is a descendant of the element with ID `ThisTable`, returns its `id` attribute and assigns it to `Selected`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPGR8/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Just:

```
$("#ThisTable tbody tr:first td:first").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code gets the first `td` of your table, then stores its `id` in a variable `Selected`.

```
var Selected = document.querySelector("#ThisTable td").id;
```

Pure DOM methods, fastest method here, and works on 91.71% of browsers according to [Can I use](http://beta.caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    console.log($($('#ThisTable').find('td')[0]).attr('id'))
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9mPw/17/